# Vue.js 2 + Bootstrap-Vue.js: Make column follow user

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vuejs2

I've been building a small test App using Vue.js and Bootstrap-Vue, lets say my App is like this:

```
    <b-container>
        <b-row>
            <b-col col md="9">
                // Page content...
            </b-col>
            <b-col col md="3">
                <cart></cart>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
```

How can I make it so the `b-col` around `cart` or `cart` itself will follow the user if he scrolls? In a similar fashion to what was available in bootstrap 3 Affix plugin?

The ideia is to have a long left/first `b-col` to show products and a right/second `b-col` with a shopping cart that follows the user around.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've a solution, considering this is the template for the `cart`:

```
<template>
<div class="cart">
    <h1>Items</h1>
    <ul>
        <li v-for=...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>
```

Just add this to the CSS:

```
div.cart {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 40px;
    height: calc(100vh - 40px);
    overflow-y: auto
}
```

Done.